# Is there a way to push a wifi signal to a Raspberry Pi with a Xamarin.Forms app

Tags: xamarin.forms, bluetooth, raspberry-pi, wifi

I am looking if there is a way with Xamarin.Form to push a wi-fi signal to a RaspBerry Pi as http://www.berrylan.org/ does.

I already tried creating an app with QT and implement Berrylands code but its not working because i developed it with Felgo

So thats why i starting developing on Xamarin.Forms, but i dont know if there is a library or a open source code that does this.

i am trying to connect a Raspberry Pi via Bluetooth and pushing the wifi password in order to connect to the Wif-fi

Comment: if they are able to do it on iOS/Anrdoid then you should be able to do it with XF.  But you need to understand **how** they are doing it - what techniques and API calls they are using, etc

Comment: @Jason well, Sonos does it, via bluetooth and its the same as BerryLan, but i dont find any docs for this or if there is a plug in or APIs